# Global variable inside the Flux Form

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I am using Typo3 6.2.14 and i want to declare the Global Variable Flux Form.

```
{namespace vt=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<f:section name="Main">
    <vt:variable.set name="test" value="2" />
    <vt:variable.set name="test" value="{vt:math.sum(a: test, fail: 2, b:2)}" />
</f:section>
```

I want to access "test" variable value Globally

Answer (score 1):

We can Set and Get Global Variable inside Flux Form Using Register.

```
<v:variable.register.set name="counter" value="1" />
```

For Getting That Variable Value using.

```
<v:variable.register.get name="counter">
```

For More information [SET](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/2.1.0/Variable/Register/SetViewHelper.html) and [GET](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/2.1.0/Variable/Register/GetViewHelper.html) Variable